# How can i correctly create a vector of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I'm new to c++ and i'm trying to create a std::vector of arrays, but whenever i push_back a new element it seems that all of the previous elements get overwritten with the new value i just added.
(I need to use the c++ default arrays rather than std::array or other containers because i need to pass them to a function that only accepts those).

The following code and output show an example of what is happening:

```
std::vector<int*> tuples;
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )      
    {
        int tuple[] = { i, j };
        tuples.push_back( tuple );      
    }
}

for( int i = 0; i < tuples.size(); i++ )        
    std::cout << i << "   " << tuples[i][0] << " " << tuples[i][1] << std::endl;
```

[At the end every array in the vector has elements {9, 4}, which are the last values reached by i and j respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2622.png)

Comment: arrays are not pointers

Comment: A pointer  is not an array.   Try using `std::vector<std::array<int ,2> >`  for `tuples` and `std::array<int, 2>` for `tuple`.    You may also want to look up `std::pair` as an alternative to `std::array<int, 2>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On each iteration of the loop, you're not pushing back the array, rather you are pushing back a *pointer* to an array with automatic storage duration which then goes out of scope. (Conceptually a new array is created on each iteration although in practice a compiler will optimise that out.)

So you end up with a `std::vector` of dangling pointers, and the behaviour on attempting to dereference those pointers is *undefined*.

A solution is to use a `std::array` for the `std::vector` payload. Note that `std::array` has a `data()` function which yields the underlying array - this will provide the compatibility with your functions that require an `int*` parameter.

Comment: To add to that: Use `std::array` and then call `data()` to get the underlying C-array if you need it

Comment: @dave: Good point: may as well make the answer useful to the OP.

Comment: Or, if old-style pointers are preferred, you can use `int* tuple = new int[2]{ i, j };` in place of `int tuple[] = { i, j };` (but then don't forget to `delete[]` each element at some point).